# Using JQuery to Automatically Assign Unpicked Option in <select> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sinatra

Newbie here.  I am building a chores list app in Sinatra. Chores are only given on 2 days; Monday or Tuesday.  There are only 2 options for chores: toys and dishes.  If a chore has been selected on Monday I would like Tuesday to automatically select the other chore.  Here is the erb:

```
<body>
<div class ="monday">
  <h2>Monday:</h2>
  <select class="button">
    <option value="lily">Lily</option>
    <option value="sam">Sam</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <select id="monday_chores" class="button">
      <option value="Dishes">X</option>
      <option value="Toys">O</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "Tuesday">
  <h2>Tuesday</h2>
  <select class="button">
    <option value="lily">Lily</option>
    <option value="sam">Sam</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <select id="tuesday_chores" class="button">
      <option value="Dishes">X</option>
      <option value="Toys">O</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <center>
    <a href="/play"><button type=button class="start_button">Start</option>
  </center>
</div>
```

I would like to achieve this by using JQuery.  I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
$(function() {
  $('#monday_chores').on ('click', function(event){
if event == Dishes
  #tuesday_chores == Toys
else
    event == Dishes
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This will select Toys when first select is changed to Dishes:

```
$(function() {
  $('#monday_chores').on ('change', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
      if (($this).val() == 'Dishes') {
          $('#tuesday_chores').val("Toys");
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

I ended up using an if else statement to make sure that the second chore was auto selected regardless of what the first chore was.  So, to extend your solution I came up with:

    $(function() {
      $('#monday_chores').on ('change', function(event){
    var $this = $(this);
    if (($this).val() == "Dishes") {
      $('#tuesday_chores').val("Toys");
    }
    else{
      $('#tuesday_chores').val("Dishes");
      }
     });
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `change` instead `click`, and to get the selected value use

```
$(this).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
$(function() {
  $('#monday_chores').on ('change', function(event){
      if ($(this).val() == 'Dishes') $('#tuesday_chores').val("Toys");
        else $('#tuesday_chores').val("Dishes");   // will select the non-selected option
  });
});
```